# Equality of 2 dicts and any of items of a list value

Tags: python

if I have dictionaries like :

```
a = {"param1": [1,2,3], "param2": "aaa", "param3": ["a", "b", "c"]}
b = {"param1": [1], "param2": "aaa", "param3": ["b", "c"]}
```

and I need to validate they are equal and return true or false neglecting the case sensitivity , also it can give true if any of the dict keys has a list value , and any of the list in the items is found in the second list
the example should give True

I have already tried :

```
shared_headers = {
        k: a[k]
        for k in a
        if k in b and (str(a[k])).lower() == (str(b[k])).lower()
}
return len(shared_headers) == len(a))
```

but it only works fine when the dicts have no list values or i just the list are exactly equal and have the same items

Comment: You need to distinguish between values that are strings and values that are lists instead of assuming that values are strings. It will be easier if you write a normal loop instead of a dictionary comprehension.

Comment: So they're equal if they have the same set of keys, and corresponding string keys are equal (case-insensitive), or if the list elements in the first are a subset of the list elements in the second?

Comment: yes , any list is subset of the other

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you mean:

```
def is_equivalent(a, b):
    if a.keys() != b.keys():
        return False
    for k in a:
        v1 = a[k]
        v2 = b[k]
        if isinstance(v1, str) and isinstance(v2, str):
            if v1.lower() != v2.lower():
                return False
        elif isinstance(v1, list) and isinstance(v2, list):
            found = False
            for x in v1:
                for y in v2:
                    try:
                        if x.lower() == y.lower():
                            found = True
                            break
                    except AttributeError:
                        if x == y:
                            found = True
                            break
            if not found:
                return False
        elif type(v1) == type(v2):
            if v1 != v2:
                return False
        else:
            return False
    return True


d1 = {"param1":[1,2,3],"param2":"aaa","param3":["a","b","c"]}
d2 = {"param1":[1],"param2":"aaa","param3":["b","c"]}

is_equivalent(d1, d2)
```

Note: If a value is not of type string or list, the two values are compared with `!=` and if they are unequal the function returns `False`. This was not part of the description but is assumed to be intended.

Comment: yes its not generic , as dict values can be anything like integers , strings  and lists

Comment: If you want that, you can easily add another default check for any other type than string and list:
elif type(v1) == type(v2):
     if v1 != v2:
        return False

Comment: `if not any(x in v2 for x in v1)` you need to add case insensitive check here as well no?

Comment: Correct, I'll edit it

Comment: but do you think its good enough to check for every data type ?

Comment: It checks specifically for string and list, because for those two types you had special requirements. If it's any other type, it makes a default comparison between the values with the != operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_equivalent(a, b):
    if a.keys() != b.keys():
        return False
    for k in a:
        v1, v2 = a[k], b[k]
        # If they're not both str or list, or they're not the same type~
        if (not all(isinstance(x, (str, list)) for x in (v1, v2))
            or type(v1) != type(v2)):
            return False
        # We already know they're the same type, so str test one and then see if equal~
        elif isinstance(v1, str) and v1.lower() != v2.lower():
            return False
        # Otherwise they're lists, and you want to know if v1 is a superset of v2~
        elif not set(v1).issuperset(v2):
            return False
    return True
```

```
>>> is_equivalent(a,b)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, let's write a function that implement the type of list equivalence you've described using a pair of calls to `all`.

```py
def list_equiv(lst1, lst2):
  return all(x in lst2 for x in lst1) or \
         all(x in lst1 for x in lst2)
```

We can then achieve this check in a single boolean expression. Python 3.8 or later is required for the walrus operator (`:=`). This heavily leans on the `A if cond else B` syntax to determine if both corresponding dictionary values are strings, lists, or other.

```py
def equiv(d1, d2):
  return (d1k := d1.keys()) == d2.keys() and \
         all(d1[k].lower() == d2[k].lower() if isinstance(d1[k], str) and \
                                               isinstance(d2[k], str) else 
             list_equiv(d1[k], d2[k]) if isinstance(d1[k], list) and \
                                         isinstance(d2[k], list) else 
             False 
             for k in d1k)
```

You could easily inline the list equivalency check into the `equiv` function.

```py
def equiv(d1, d2):
  return (d1k := d1.keys()) == d2.keys() and \
          all(d1[k].lower() == d2[k].lower() \
                if isinstance(d1[k], str) and \
                   isinstance(d2[k], str) else 
              all(x in d2[k] for x in d1[k]) or \
              all(x in d1[k] for x in d2[k]) \
                if isinstance(d1[k], list) and \
                   isinstance(d2[k], list) else 
              False 
              for k in d1k)
```